# Nuxt 3 useFetch POST request send a 419 unknown status error

Tags: laravel, csrf, nuxtjs3, laravel-sanctum

I develop a web app with NuxtJS and Laravel.

When I send a POST request with useFetch, I have a 419 error, and no more information (it is an unknown status).

I launch sanctum/csrf-cookie request, and keep token in variable :

```
var token;

await useFetch("http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie",
    {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include"
    }
).then(() => {
    token = document.cookie
                    .split("; ")
                    .find((row) => row.startsWith("XSRF-TOKEN"))
                    ?.split("=")[1];
});
```

And I launch

```
await useFetch(
    'http://localhost:8000/login',
    {
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token,
        },
        body:{
            "email": "ukeeling@example.org",
            "password": "password",
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: "include"
    }
).then(loginResponse => {
    console.log("login", loginResponse.data);
});
```

This is my route in web.php :

```
Route::post('login', function(Request $request){
     return "Log In";
};
```

this is my cors.php config file :

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'logout',],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:8000', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

GET request works but not POST.
And, if I add "/login" route in $except attribute in VerifyCsrfToken, the login POST request works.
And, all route work on Postman.

I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer !

I compare CSRF token send by Laravel and the retrieved token with the document.cookie.
They are similar when I read it, but I put their in a new document (in VSCode) and I highlight letter by letter.
There is a letter not recognize as same.

So, Laravel doesn't match my token with his token, because there are different.

To resolve it, I do :

```
token = decodeURIComponent(token);
```

And it works !